# offset().top - (something) repeats

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, offset

I'm trying to dynamically open a tab with Bootstrap and smoothly scroll down to it at the same time. I have it mostly functional, except that the offset().top-280 I'm using causes the screen to shift up 280px every time it's touched. I'd like to scroll to the div on the first button and afterward, just stay put when clicking the other handles.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="join-options" data-tabs="tabs">
 <li><a href="#donate" data-toggle="tab">Donate</a></li>
 <li><a href="#join-new" data-toggle="tab">Join</a></li>
 <li><a href="#renew" data-toggle="tab">Renew</a></li>
</ul>
```

Those were the handles. Now the content:

```
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="donate">
    <h1>Donate</h1>
<p>donate donate donate donate donate donate</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="join-new">
    <h1>Join</h1>
<p>join join join join join</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="renew">
<h1>Renew</h1>
<p>renew renew renew renew renew</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
        $('.join-options a').bind('click', function(event) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-280)
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get it, but you could just set a variable when the page scrolls the first time, and remove the scrolling on subsequent clicks etc ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var touched = false;

    $('#tabs').tab();

    $('.join-options a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!touched) {

            var $anchor = $(this);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-280)
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        }
        touched = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant-- I wanted to use an if statement but I'm a total js newb. Thanks!